# Hugo: End content summary at first paragraph break

Tags: hugo

I'm trying to migrate a blog from Jekyll, and I'd like to keep my excerpts/content summaries the same. That is, I'd like to automatically end the summary at the first paragraph break.

```
I should be included in the content summary.
Still in summary.

This is no longer part of summary
```

The docs seem to indicate that Hugo only supports automatic summaries [by length](https://gohugo.io/content-management/summaries/#automatic-summary-splitting).

Is there some way to automatically break the content summary on the first paragraph break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it working, based on Rogelio's answer:

```
{{ $summary := index (split .Content "</p>") 0 }}
```

The code above splits the content of the whole article by closing `p` tag, retrieves the first element of the resulting array, and stores it in the `$summary` variable.

The key to this solution resides in:

1. Using the whole content instead of the summary, so your first paragraph will be kept no matter how long it is.
2. Splitting the content by closing `</p>` and **not** the opening `<p>` tag.

At this point, `$summary` contains this code:

```
<p>
I should be included in the content summary.
Still in summary.
```

After that, we can output the summary. Just make sure to remove HTML using with `plainify`, to get rid of the unclosed `<p>` tag.

```
{{ $summary | plainify }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a shortcode or partial - depending on where you are using it.
Use the .Summary variable
Use the Split function.

Psuedo-code:

```
{{ split .Summary "<p>" }}
```

Which will give you a map/slice/array of values.

So more psuedo code:

```
{{ index (split .Summary "<p>") 0 }}
```

etc.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It looks like hugo strips html and newlines from the summary. 
I'm pretty new to hugo though, I may be misunderstanding

Comment: | safeHTML OR | markdownify
Meaning, I'm not near my dev station so you are going to have to work/check docs a bit, something like: 
{{ (index (split .Summary "<p>") 0) | markdownify }} Or split by another value than <p>

Answer (score 1):

No, Hugo supports more than summaries by length.

There are multiple ways in which a summary can be specified and it is useful to understand the order of selection Hugo follows when deciding on the text to be returned by .Summary. It is as follows:

- If there is a  summary divider present in the article the text up to the divider will be provided as per the manual summary split method
- If there is a *summary* variable in the article front matter the value of the variable will be provided as per the front matter summary method
- The text at the start of the article will be provided as per the automatic summary split method

Hugo uses the first of the above steps that returns text. So if, for example, your article has both summary variable in its front matter and a  summary divider Hugo will use the manual summary split method.

Make sure there are no blanks in between.

```
<!--more-->
```

or

```
summary: Here your first paragraph, but be careful, you 
         have to copy it so that it appears twice in the
         file. IMO this is only advantageous if you want to 
         make a difference to the text in the summary. ....
```

Comment: It's certainly good to understand those options, but was thinking of automatic in terms of the [documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/summaries/#automatic-summary-splitting). It refers to the more divider as manual splitting, and I'd consider front matter even more manual.
I ended up just using a complex find-replace to insert <!--more--> into each of my posts